# Saving multiple file types into one potobuf-net'ized file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, types, protobuf-net, save

I'm writing a program that saves 'map' files to the HD so that I can open them later and display the same data.  My maps originally saved only one data type, a set of my own custom objects with the properties:  `id`, `layer`, `x`, and `y`.  You can see the code I did for that, here:

```
<ProtoContract()> _
Public Class StrippedElement
    <ProtoMember(1)> _
    Public Property X() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_X
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_X = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_X As Integer
    <ProtoMember(2)> _
    Public Property Y() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Y
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_Y = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Y As Integer
    <ProtoMember(3)> _
    Public Property Id() As Long
        Get
            Return m_Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            m_Id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Id As Long
    <ProtoMember(4)> _
    Public Property Layer() As String
        Get
            Return m_Layer
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Layer = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Layer As String
End Class
```

Basically, I'm just serializing tons and tons of these classes into one file.  Now I've come to find out that I have to save new parts of the map that aren't necessarily the same class type.

Is it possible to save multiple types to the same file and still read from it just as simply?  Here is my code to write and read to/from the file:

```
    Public Shared Sub Save(ByVal File As String, ByVal Map As RedSimEngine.Map)
        Dim nPBL As New List(Of StrippedElement)
        For z As Integer = 0 To Grid.LAYERLIMIT
            For x As Integer = 0 To Grid.GRIDLIMIT
                For y As Integer = 0 To Grid.GRIDLIMIT
                    Dim currentCell As GridElement = Map.Level.getCell(z, x, y)
                    If currentCell IsNot Nothing Then
                        If currentCell.Archivable Then
                            Dim nStEl As New StrippedElement
                            nStEl.Id = currentCell.getId()
                            nStEl.Layer = currentCell.getLayer()
                            nStEl.X = currentCell.X
                            nStEl.Y = currentCell.Y
                            nPBL.Add(nStEl)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
        Serializer.Serialize(New FileStream(File, FileMode.Create), nPBL)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Load(ByVal File As String) As RedSimEngine.Map
        Dim nMap As New Map
        Dim nListOfSE As List(Of StrippedElement) = Serializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of StrippedElement))(New FileStream(File, FileMode.Open))
        For Each elm As StrippedElement In nListOfSE
            Dim nElm As GridElement = GridElement.createElementByIdAndLayer(elm.Layer, elm.Id)
            nElm.X = elm.X
            nElm.Y = elm.Y
            nMap.Level.setCell(nElm)
        Next
        Return nMap
    End Function
```

I have to add 3 or more class types to the save file, I'd rather not have it split up because then it would get confusing for my clients.

Basically, I have to add things similar to the following:

- A class with **`X`**, **`Y`**, and **`Value`**
- A class with **`Name`** and **`Value`**
- A class with **`Name`**, **`ENUMVALUE`**, **`X`**, **`Y`**, **`INTEGERVALUE`**, and a couple other things (This one will have to contain quite a bit of data).

I'm using VB.net so all .net answers are acceptable.  Thanks!  If you need any clarification, just say so in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options here:

The first option is to write a wrapper class with 3 containers:

```
 [ProtoContract] public class MyData {
     [ProtoMember(1)] public List<Foo> SomeName {get;set;} // x,y,value
     [ProtoMember(2)] public List<Bar> AnotherName {get;set;} // name,value
     [ProtoMember(3)] public List<Blap> ThirdName {get;set;} // etc
 }
```

and serialize an instance of that; note, however, that the order will be lost here - i.e. after deserializing there is no difference between `Foo0, Bar0, Foo1` and `Foo0, Foo1, Bar0` - either will result in `SomeName` with `Foo0` and `Foo1`, and `AnotherName` with `Bar0`. This option is compatible with your existing data, as internally there is no difference between serializing "a list of Foo" vs "a wrapper class with a list of Foo as field 1".

The second option is to mimic the above, but with a manual type-check during deserialization -this involves using the non-generic API and providing a delegate that maps field numbers (1,2,3) to types (`Foo`,`Bar`,`Blap`). This is useful for very large streams, or selectively plucking objects *from* the stream, as it allows you to process individual objects (or ignore them) individually. With this approach you can also *build* the file cumulatively rather than building an entire list. The example is a bit more complex, though, so I'd rather not add one unless it is of interest. This approach is compatible with your existing data.

The third approach is inheritance, i.e.

```
[ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Foo))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Bar)), ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Blap))]
public class SomeBaseType {}

[ProtoContract] public class Foo : SomeBaseType { /* properties etc*/ }
[ProtoContract] public class Bar: SomeBaseType { /* properties etc*/ }
[ProtoContract] public class Blap: SomeBaseType { /* properties etc*/ }
```

then serialize a `List<SomeBaseType>` which happens to *contain* instances that are `Foo` / `Bar` / `Blap`. This is simple and convenient, and preserves order nicely; but it is not *quite* compatible with data serialized simply as a `List<Foo>` - if existing serialized data is an issue you will need to migrate between the formats.

Comment: @OP You've saved me again Mr. Gravell!  I just implemented the Wrapper method you provided without a single hitch!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

i find "Serializer.Serialize" very unclean in this kind of cases, so here is how i would proceed :
i would write variables manually one at time!

for example, here is how i would write and read a StrippedElement :

```
    Sub WriteStrippedElement(ByVal Stream As IO.Stream, ByVal SE As StrippedElement)
    Stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(SE.X), 0, 4) 'Write X:integer (4 bytes)
    Stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(SE.Y), 0, 4) 'Write Y:integer (4 bytes)
    Stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(SE.Id), 0, 8) 'Write Id:Long (8 bytes)
    Dim LayerBuffer() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(SE.Layer) 'Converting String To Bytes
    Stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(LayerBuffer.Length), 0, 4) 'Write The length of layer, since it can't have a fixed size:integer (4 bytes)
    Stream.Write(LayerBuffer, 0, LayerBuffer.Length) 'Write The Layer Data
    Stream.Flush() 'We're Done :)
End Sub
Sub ReadStrippedElement(ByVal Stream As IO.Stream, ByRef SE As StrippedElement)
    Dim BinRead As New IO.BinaryReader(Stream) 'Making reading Easier, We can also use a BinaryWriter in the WriteStrippedElement For example
    SE.X = BinRead.ReadInt32 'Read 4 Bytes
    SE.Y = BinRead.ReadInt32 'Read 4 Bytes
    SE.Id = BinRead.ReadInt64 'Read 8 Bytes
    Dim Length As Integer = BinRead.ReadInt32 'Read 4 Bytes, the length of Layer
    Dim LayerBuffer() As Byte = BinRead.ReadBytes(Length) 'Read Layer Bytes
    SE.Layer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(LayerBuffer) 'Convert Back To String, and done.
End Sub
```

So if you like to write alot of those StrippedElement, just write down the number of elements (int32, 4bytes) to know how much to read from the file next time.

Comment: Unless you know *exactly* what you are doing, and need it to be *absolutely tight*, serialization is, IMO, best left to tools that won't make annoying subtle errors (for example, a "reader" (`BinaryReader`) declared local to a method might easily over-consume a stream into the buffer... BOOM!). It isn't code that most people should need to care about. Also: consider "endianness" (might be running on mono). Finally, why is `SE` (known the be a class) declared `ByRef` in the final example?

Comment: Because i will need that SE outside of the Sub, it's a global Variable..
Dim SE as StrippedElement'It is Empty
ReadStrippedElement(MyFileStream,SE)
Dim x as integer = SE.X 'Now SE contains Data

Comment: That doesn't change anything... it is a class; as soon as you've set `SE.X`, you've updated the object. You would only need `ByRef` if you were *reassigning* the parameter value to a new instance, and needed that *assignment* to be visible to the caller - i.e. `SE = new StrippedElement();` (or the VB equivalent). Your code doesn't have an assignment (and a `Function` would probably be easier)

Comment: Yes, a function is probably easier, but i usally code in this way, and make the function returns a boolean (error handling)